# exp_cookie_settings error on update

Tags: update

I'm updating manually from EE 3.5.10 to EE 6. When I try to load admin.php in my browser to start the update I get the following error:

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db196778_nape.exp_cookie_settings' doesn't exist:
SELECT CookieSetting_cookie_settings.cookie_id as CookieSetting__cookie_id, CookieSetting_cookie_settings.cookie_provider as CookieSetting__cookie_provider, CookieSetting_cookie_settings.cookie_name as CookieSetting__cookie_name FROM (`exp_cookie_settings` as CookieSetting_cookie_settings) WHERE ( `CookieSetting_cookie_settings`.`cookie_provider` IN ('ee', 'cp') ) LIMIT 18446744073709551615

exp_cookie_settings does not exist in the database to begin with under EE 3.5.10 so I'm not sure why the updater is looking for that table.

Any ideas how I can get this update working? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. For some reason, my ee folder was missing the installer folder. Once I replaced it, the installer worked.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a .env.php file? If so, make sure that you have the install mode set to true: `putenv('EE_INSTALL_MODE=TRUE');`

Comment: Where would that file be located if I had one?

Comment: It's normally in the web root directory. So if my EE install was at `/var/www/html/ee` my environment file would normally be at `/var/www/html/ee/.env.php`. Glad you got it figured out!